# How do I configure IntelliJ to insert <p> tags into existing javadoc?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I have configured my Android Studio (IntelliJ) to insert <p> characters on empty new lines in javadoc by checking the check box in `Preferences > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc.`

However, when I apply my formatter to my existing code base (`Code > Reformat Code...`), the <p> tags are not inserted.

My question is, how do I get the IDE to apply the formatter successfully for javadoc newline <p> tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If you have JavaDoc like this:

```
/**
 * Text
 *               <- no tag will be added here
 * @author foo
 */
```

The `<p/>` tag will not be inserted between `Text` and `@author`, because it would serve no purpose there. The tags will only be inserted between lines of the description (the first part of the JavaDoc):

```
/**
 * Text 1
 *               <- <p/> will be inserted on this line after reformat
 * Text 2
 *               <- no tag will be inserted here
 * @author foo
 */
```

I'm not certain if this is the problem you're experiencing. Let me know in the comments if it works for you with multiline description as in the second example or if it doesn't work at all.